# React replace event.target with input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**UPDATE**
Here's are some demos

[contentEditable demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pknxkv11jx) - *requires double click for H1 to become editable*

[replace with input demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wy6v9lkmnk) - *adopts `event.target` styles but makes the UI 'twitch' when rendered*

---

So I have some functional components, let's say:

**component1.js**

```
import React from 'react';
const component1 = props => (
<div>
 <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
);
export { component1 };
```

They are variable. `event.target` could be anything with text, so paragraph, heading, anything. I'm trying to let users edit content inline by clicking on it, so I'll pass a function `editMode` to these functional components, that'll update parent state with editing info, let's say like this:

`<h1 onClick={event => {editMode(event, props.name, props.title, 'title')}}>title</h1>`

This changes parent local state to have all the necessary information to grab the value from redux, define a target etc. For this example, `props.name` is the name of the component, `props.title` is the value, and `'title'` is object key in redux.

So I'll add something to my **component1.js** and make it look a bit like this:

```
import React from 'react';
const component1 = props => (
    <div>
        {props.editState === 'true' &&
            <EditLayout
                name={props.name}
                target={props.target}
                value={props.value}
                onChange={event => someFunc(event)}
            />
        }
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    );
export { component1 };
```

Now this works fine, except it doesn't scale. `EditLayout`, in this case, will just return an input with correct value. What I need it to do is to adapt to whatever is being clicked, get font size, background, padding, margin, position. Am I doing this right? Every way I try, I run into huge issues:

**Idea 1 - move `EditLayout` component outside of the functional component**

*Issue: positioning*

So I'll move EditLayout to parent component that contains both `component1.js` and `EditLayout`. This will allow me to manipulate it from inside the functional component, without having to include it everywhere. I'll then grab coordinates and other important information from `event.target` like so:

```
const coords = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
const offsetX = coords.left;
const offsetY = coords.top;
const childHeight = coords.height;
const childWidth = coords.width;
const childClass = event.target.className;
```

I'll then wrap the `EditLayout` to return a container which contains an input, and apply size/coordinates to the absolutely positioned container. This'll present an issue of input being offset by a random amount of pixels, depending on how big/where is the `event.target`.

**Idea 2 - pass relevant computed styles to `EditLayout`**

*Issue: twitching on render, and I have to add `EditLayout` for every possible `event.target` there is, as well as condition its' render*

So I'll grab all important computed styles like this:

```
const computedTarget = window.getComputedStyle(event.target);
const childMargins = computedTarget.marginBottom;
const childPaddings = computedTarget.padding;
const childFontSize = computedTarget.fontSize;
const childTextAlign = computedTarget.textAlign;
```

And pass it to `component1.js`, and then pass it to `EditLayout` component inside the `component1.js. I'll then condition the`event.target to hide if it's being edited like this:

```
<h1 className={ props.target === 'title' ? 'd-none' : ''}>Title</h1>
```

And condition the `EditLayout` to show only if it's needed:

```
{props.target === 'title' && <EditLayout />}
```

In this example, clicking h1 will show the input, but the layout itself with twitch on render. Input will have the exact same margin and font size as the h1, or `event.target`, but it'll appear bigger and extend the layout. Demo:

[image]

**Idea 3 - Use conditional contentEditable**

*Issue: Requires double click to enable, doesn't work in safari, doesn't let me preselect the value*

This is the weirdest of them all. I figured it'd be pretty simple, do something like this inside the functional component render:

`<h1 contentEditable={props.target === 'title'} onClick={event => props.setTarget(event)}>Title</h1>`

However, I have to double click to enable it. I have no idea why, if I attach a console log every time `onClick` is fired, I'll get correct outputs, I'll get the correct target value as well. I've tried numerous ways, but it simply requires double click. Even attempted to handle this inside the functional component, as most of the stuff is handled by a parent component, doesn't make a difference.

I have oversimplified the examples, so it's safe to assume/understand the following:

- I am passing props in a correct fashion, they aren't undefined
- I am using bootstrap
- I am using styled components, and `EditLayout` is a styled component
  which accepts props and turns them into CSS like: `font-size: ${props
  => props.fontSize};`
- The values should be correct, I am not manipulating anything I get back from `getComputedStyle()` or `getBoundingClientRect()`
- I am keen on keeping my functional components functional, and easy to
  add. Functional components, in this case, are simple HTML structures,
  and I'd like to keep them as simple as possible

Comment: Have you considered using `contentEditable` and binding to the input event vs trying to clone everything?

Comment: Yes, however, it doesn't give me enough control, it works only on double click (not sure why), and it straight up doesn't work in safari. So I figured having an input is more friendly and easier to control.

Comment: Regarding `event.target` usage. Assuming we are talking about native JavaScript's `event.target`. Please read up on [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) and be sure that `event.target` is exactly what you want. Generally `currentTarget` is safer; because, it is much more predictable than `target`. `currentTarget` always refers to the element that the event is attached to and `target` refers to the element that the event occurred on.

Comment: So @Tyler I haven't had any issues about the event.target being wrong, since I was permanently logging every step of the process due to passing a lot of stuff around, but I will try and update to currentTarget to see if it'll make any difference. I assume you're aiming to fix `contentEditable` approach

Comment: @PredragBeocanin Actually it's probably unrelated to your problem. It's just a possible future bug; because, `target` is not guaranteed to reference the same element every time. Since `currentTarget` always refers to the same element it is much more predictable and safer to use.

Comment: @Tyler gotcha, thank you, I'll make sure to update those as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a neat solution to `contentEditable` requiring two clicks instead of one, instead of binding `onClick` and passing it to enable `contentEditable`, simply keep `contentEditable` true and handle the change however you like. Here's a working `h1` that doesn't require two clicks to enable `contentEditable`, unlike the one in the demo

```
<h1
    className="display-4 text-center"
    contentEditable
    suppressContentEditableWarning
    onBlur={event =>  updateValues(event)}
>
    Title 
</h1>
```

The available methods for trigger update could be `onBlur` or `onInput`.